# Why does $orders appear to be empty in the second loop?

Tags: php

Been toying around with a simple php script for my homework using an array. I left even the comments from the troubleshooting, and finally found that if I put the for loop that iterates through $orders inside the while loop that it outputs the file contents the way I'd like to. The really weird part, is that the second loop, STILL outputs nothing. NOTHING. I found out that fgetcsv goes through the file one line at a time, and so it keeps getting either overwritten or extending onto the end of the array (I assumed the later, but it doesn't appear to work that way?) But even if that was the case, shouldn't the second for loop that iterates through $orders at least dump the last line in the file?

```
<html>
<title>Bob's Auto Array</title>
<body>
<?php

echo "<h1>Bob's Auto Parts</h1>";
echo "<h2>Customer Orders</h2>";
$order = 0;
$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/prg240/orders.txt", 'r');

#$file = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/prg240/orders.txt");
#echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/prg240/orders.txt";

if ($file) {
echo count($file);
while (!feof($file)) {
$order = fgetcsv($file, 99999, "\t");
for($i = 0; $i < count($order);$i++)
    echo "<p>".$order[$i]."</p>";
}
#fclose($file);
}

for($i = 0;$i < count($order);$i++)
echo "<p>".$order[$i]."</p>";
fclose($file);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why `$order = fgetcsv($file, 99999, "\t");` in loop?

Comment: your loop doesn't make sense, `$i = 0; $i < count($order);$i++` but your `$order = 0`?

Comment: Because that's how the book does it? fgetcsv pulls line by line, right? Or does it automatically pull all the way to the end of hte file without the !feof clause?

$order doesn't = 0, there's a line in there for `$order = fgetcsv($file, 99999, "\t");` I put the $order=0; thing in there because while trying to figure out what was going on, I thought maybe it was some kind of weird scoping issue where $orders wasn't a thing outside of the loop where I set it to fgetcsv.

I'm still wondering why the first for loop outputs the contents of the file, and the second loop outputs nothing.